# What value should I use for Side in a FIX-Protocol message to buy a foreign currency with EUR/USD and USD/CAD?

Tags: fix-protocol, trading, forex

From reading the information about **`NewOrderSingle`** FIX-Protocol message on [FIXimate](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/) I can't figure out how to properly use the Side, tag **`54=`**.

For the below orders, what are the correct sides?

- Buy `CAD`, sell `USD`: Symbol is `USD/CAD`, Side needs to be 1 or 2?
- Buy `EUR`, sell `USD`: Symbol is `EUR/USD`, Side needs to be 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking whether the instrument is quoted as base/terms currency or the inverse.

That depends on your counterparty and the FIX-Protocol specification that you and they specify together.

Usually it's baseCCY/termsCCY and the answer to your question is <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd>:
the <kbd>2</kbd> to buy termsCCY, the CAD in USDCAD,
and
the <kbd>1</kbd> to buy baseCCY, the EUR of EURUSD.

So you see you can use either case as shown by your CADUSD example. That's because a client, for example, may want to buy **`1.000.000`** USD of EURUSD (in other words a nice round figure amount quoted in USD) but with the price quoted in the conventional EURUSD and not as the unconventional USDEUR.

In that case it would be <kbd>2</kbd> to buy USD (and sell EUR).

From memory I think the baseCCY, or dealt currency, FIX-Protocol tag is **`12=`** or **`15=`**, and that removes any ambiguity about the size and side and currency quoting convention.

No doubt you get what I am talking about tho.